# spatial distribution of points, R

Tags: r, distribution, point, spatial

What would be an easy way to generate a 3 different spatial distribution of points (N = 20 points) using R. For example, 1) random, 2) uniform, and 3) clustered on the same space (50 x 50 grid)?

Comment: what exactly do you mean in (2) by 20 uniform points on a 50x50 grid, given that from (1) you apparently don't mean 'random uniform' ... (on the other hand, if you do, what does (1) mean at all)? If you don't mean random, you can't make it exactly uniform, so what should be optimized?

Comment: So, for the random distribution I can use x<-runif(N,0,50);y<-runif(N,0,50), but for the Uniform distribution I want the points equally spaced from each other

Comment: Except, as I already explained, you really *can't* make them exactly equally spaced; you can get 'close', but closeness could be measured in many ways. What should be optimized?

Comment: Are you, for example, looking for minimum-discrepancy sequences, or something else?

Comment: One thing you might want to consider is how you'd arrange 5 points in a 25 x 25 grid.

Comment: I should clarify - you can make them 'equally spaced' in some senses, but not necessarily in all senses; you have to work out what you're trying to achieve. I made a reasonable assumption in generating my first answer below, which gives pretty good results (it's uniform in a bunch of senses)

Comment: For posterity, it looks like there might be some good leads in the spatstat package. Check out the spatstat::rpoispp() function documentation (https://rdrr.io/cran/spatstat/man/rpoispp.html) and the additional function suggestions in the "See Also" section there.

Answer (score 0):

1) Here's one way to get a very even spacing of 5 points in a 25 by 25 grid numbered from 1 each direction. Put points at (3,18), (8,3), (13,13), (18,23), (23,8); you should be able to generalize from there.

2) as you suggest, you could use `runif` ... but I'd have assumed from your question you actually wanted points on the lattice (i.e. integers), in which case you might use `sample`.

Are you sure you want continuous rather than discrete random variables?

3) This one is "underdetermined" - depending on how you want to define things there's a bunch of ways you might do it. e.g. if it's on a grid, you could sample points in such a way that points close to (but not exactly on) already sampled points had a much higher probability than ones further away; a similar setup works for continuous variables. Or you could generate more points than you need and eliminate the loneliest ones. Or you could start with random uniform points and them make them gravitate toward their neighbors. Or you could generate a few cluster-centers (4-10, say), and then scatter points about those centers. Or you could do any of a hundred other things.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but the answers above do not really address the problem. Here is what you are looking for:

```
library(sp)

# make a grid of size 50*50
x1<-seq(1:50)-0.5
x2<-x1
grid<-expand.grid(x1,x2)
names(grid)<-c("x1","x2")

# make a grid a spatial object
coordinates(grid) <- ~x1+x2
gridded(grid) <- TRUE
```

First: random sampling

```
# random sampling
random.pt <- spsample(x = grid, n= 20, type = 'random')
```

Second: regular sampling

```
# regular sampling
regular.pt <- spsample(x = grid, n= 20, type = 'regular')
```

Third: clustered at a distance of 2 from a random location (can go outside the area)

```
# random sampling of one location 
ori <- data.frame(spsample(x = grid, n= 1, type = 'random'))

# select randomly 20 distances between 0 and 2
n.point <- 20 
h <- rnorm(n.point, 1:2) 

# empty dataframe
dxy <- data.frame(matrix(nrow=n.point, ncol=2))

# take a random angle from the randomly selected location and make a dataframe of the new distances from the original sampling points, in a random direction
angle <- runif(n = n.point,min=0,max=2*pi)
dxy[,1]= h*sin(angle)
dxy[,2]= h*cos(angle)
cluster <- data.frame(x=rep(NA, 20), y=rep(NA, 20))
cluster$x <- ori$coords.x1 + dxy$X1
cluster$y <- ori$coords.x2 + dxy$X2

# make a spatial object and plot
coordinates(cluster)<-  ~ x+y
plot(grid)
plot(cluster, add=T, col='green')
plot(random.pt, add=T, col= 'red')
plot(regular.pt, add=T, col= 'blue')
```